# Various foreground color in SWT Combo Comboviewer list of strings

Tags: java, swt

I have a combo with a list of strings in the select list. If the user pulldown list of strings, some foreground color will be black (standard) and other defined strings should the foreground color green or red. How do I render this in order to achieve this? 
I think that must be solved with ComboViewer, but I have no idea?

Answer (score 3):

A SWT `Combo` doesn't provide this functionality, which is due to the native widgets used for Combo, I believe.

That's why there is a widget in Nebula, which adds such features by internally using a `Table` to draw the Combo. See [here](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php) for screenshots and information how to use it.

(Nebula is a collection of useful custom widgets for SWT.)